# Sharing Data Between Greasemonkey Scripts

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

How can I share a string value between two scripts?  I want to set the value in the first script on page one.  I click a link which loads a second page from a different domain.  I want to read the string from the second script on page two.

Answer (score 0):

If you had both scripts running at the same time, you could create your own [MessageEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

Otherwise, you will need a single script that runs on both domains.